# Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения temp было (адрес)

Tags: c++, исключения, стек

Стек на основе односявязного списка,нужно организовать функции push(),pop() и print()

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class INF, class FRIEND>
class ListNode // узел(элемент)
{
private:
    INF d; //данные
    ListNode * next; //указатель на след элемент односвязного списка
    ListNode(void) //реализация конструктора
    {
        d = 0;
        next = nullptr;
    }
    ~ListNode()//деструктор
    {

    }  
    friend FRIEND;
};

template<class INF>
class Stack
{
    typedef class ListNode < INF, Stack <INF> > Node;//класс Stack это дружественный класс к кдассу ListNode. Node это новое имя(для удобства)
    Node *top;// указатель на вершину стека
public:
    void push(INF obj); // прототипы функции добавления элемента в стек
    void print(); //прототип функции печати
    void pop();
};

template<class INF>
void Stack<INF>::push(INF obj)
{

    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->d = obj;
    if (top == nullptr)// проверка есть ли в стеке элемент
        temp->next = nullptr;
    else
        temp->next = top;
    top = temp;
}

template<class INF>
void Stack<INF>::pop()
{
    Node *temp = top;// временный объект который хранит первый элемент

    top = top->next;// хранит адрес след элемента после первого(после top)

    delete temp;// удаляем бывший первый элемент
}

template<class INF>
void Stack<INF>::print()
{
    cout << "Содержимое стека: ";
    Node * temp = top;

    while (temp != nullptr)
    {
        cout << temp->d << ' '; 
        temp = temp->next; // Очень важно - навигация по списку 
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: добавил в начало pop строку `if (top == nullptr) return;` и оно перестало падать на пустом.

Comment: Я добавила такую строку в начало функции pop(), но исключение никуда не пропало((

Comment: Это исключение было ещё до добавления функции pop()

Comment: тогда показывайте, как Вы используете свой класс

Comment: #include<iostream>
#include"Header.h"
using namespace std;

void Multipliers(int n, Stack <int> &stack)//(число,которое нужно разбить на мнж,простые множители)
{
 system("chcp 1251 > null");
 int N;
 int div = 2;
 Stack<int> s;
 cout << "Введите число" << endl;
 cin >> N;
 while (N > 1)
 {
  while (N % div == 0)
  {
   cout << "*" << endl;
   N = N / div;
   s.push(N);
  }
  div++;
 }
}

int main()
{
 system("chcp 1251 > null");

 Stack<int> s1;
 s1.push(23);
 s1.push(34);
 s1.print();
 Multipliers(284, s1);
 system("pause");
}

Comment: Ой,в строчку неудобно,можно ли как-то по -другому отправить код?

Comment: можно отредактировать вопрос. Но в любом случае, я его уже скопировал, ничего не падает

Comment: Ох,как странно, попробую создать новый проект и скопировать туда код.

Comment: Создала новый проект, но не помогло(Но в любом случаем,спасибо за помощь

Comment: А у Вас 17 версия Visual Studio или 19?

Comment: у меня gcc/clang, но не думаю, что это важно.